# Implantação de mais de um .war no contexto root do Glassfish

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

Tenho duas aplicações que preciso fazer deploy no GlassFish e gostaria de saber como colocar as duas no contexto raiz do mesmo GlassFish. Sei que, para colocar uma aplicação no contexto raiz, devo colocar a seguinte linha no glassfish-web.xml:

```
 <context-root>/</context-root>
```

Assim, sempre que acessar http://localhost:8080 será aberta minha aplicação. Mas como implantar as duas no contexto raiz? Terei de mudar a porta?

Comment: Qualquer uma das aplicações, Alexandre. Eu preciso que as duas executem sem eu ter que colocar localhost:8080/projeto1 e localhost:8080/projeto2, para eu poder linkar com o DNS certinho. Ambas devem ficar assim: {ip}:{porta}/.

Comment: @LeoPinheiroDeSouza já olhou sobre virtual servers? eu utilizo o mesmo glassfish com um site e um sistema rodando, porém com nome de dominio diferente. Se você entrar no admin console e ir em `server Config > virtual servers > new >`você pode configurar o ip que vai ser direcionado sua aplicação.

Comment: Eu não percebo muito bem o que tu pretendes. De qualquer das maneiras podes ir a:http://localhost:4848/ (consola do Glassfish) e ires a Applications e lá consegues ver as diferentes aplicações que fizeste deploy. Depois é só escolheres a aplicação que queres correr fazendo Launch.

Comment: Faça o deploy de cada aplicação em seu próprio contexto e crie um virtual server para cada.